# Not Able to Sort the data in DATASTORE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to sort my data in ascending order , but the Query is not working.can somebody please help me in that.My Query is:

```
    Query q444=new Query("depmaster").addSort("departmentName" ,SortDirection.ASCENDING);
```

Comment: Is `departmentName` an indexed field?

Comment: You may be able to get more help if you provide both the entity definition, the code where you create the entities, and a more detailed description of what about it isn't working (error, no results, etc).

Comment: Hi, sorry I did a silly mistake i didnot imported library file , now it is working fine.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the "departmentName" property is indexed.

Comment: "depmaster" is the entity name , and "departmentName " is one of the column name in my entity "depmaster"

Comment: We can see that from your query (except in the datastore we use the word "property", not column). Make sure that it's indexed.

Comment: Hi, sorry I did a silly mistake i didnot imported library file , now it is working fine.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You have just created a query. You need to create prepared query and then receive the query result. You need to get the results. The typical steps are:

```
DatastoreService datastoreService = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Query query = new Query("IMAGES").setFilter(new Query.FilterPredicate("id",Query.FilterOperator.GREATER_THAN, 0))
PreparedQuery pq = datastoreService.prepare(query);
```